# How to upload SQL file into MinIO?

Tags: sql, minio

Version of MinIO:
`minio-20220724170931.0.0-1.x86_64`

Q:
Upload text file, within SQL `*select * from *`, will cause a **403 error**.
After testing, as long as these will report errors, with drop /delete from and other problems.
Only TXT files tested will do this, neither does excel.

I suspect it's MinIO's built-in security against SQL injection attacks.
How would one be able to remove this?